# The proof of an inequality in Linear Algebra and its Applications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the paper *"On some inequalities for unitarily invariant norms and singular values"* for Limin Zou and Chuanjiang He, it was stated that for $A$ and $B$ positive semidefinite the inequality
$$\|AB+ BA\| \le \|A^2+B^2\|$$ can be directly derived from a previous inequality $$\|A^\frac{1}{2}XB^\frac{1}{2}\| \le \left\|\frac{A^vXB^{1-v} +A^{1-v}XB^v}{2}\right\|\le \left\|\frac{AX+XB}{2}\right\|$$
where $0\le v\le 1$ $A,B,X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $A$ and $B$ positive semidefinite.

How can I derive it?

Comment: Presumably $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite in the first inequality as well?  It's not true in general.

Comment: There's a typo in the second equality. The $AX+BX$ in the numerator of the fraction on the RHS should read $AX+XB$.

Comment: Yes I am sorry I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A,B$ are Hermitian and the norm is unitarily invariant, we have $\|AB\|=\|BA\|$. Therefore $\|AB+BA\|\le\|AB\|+\|BA\|=2\|AB\|$. As $A$ is PSD, $A^2$ is also PSD and $(A^2)^{1/2}=A$. And the similar holds for $B$. Therefore, using the given inequality, we obtain
$$
2\|AB\|=2\left\|(A^2)^{1/2}I(B^2)^{1/2}\right\|
\le2\left\|\frac{(A^2)I+I(B^2)}{2}\right\|=\|A^2+B^2\|
$$
and we are done.